# CC documents to third party sent to signer for view only in envelope

Tags: json, rest, docusignapi

We have the need to send a different email to a third party (with a different template to that received by the signers) at the same time as emailing the docs to the signers. Third party will be viewing documents only sent to signers. We need to do it using restapi call.

See image attached for template and view document button.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with Document Visibility -- making the special template viewable to only the extra cc person. (And making all of the other content not visible to that person.)

First use this [guide](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-document-visibility) to try out Document Visibility by using the DocuSign web tool. Once it is working to your satisfaction, you can use the API to automate the process.